# Is it possible to open devtools to inspect the devtools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to theme the chrome devtools (it works to use ones provided here, http://devthemez.com/themes/chrome-developer-tools, but I want to make my own)

It's really hard for me (near impossible) to theme without knowing the markup. Is it possible to open the devtools for the devtools? If not, how can I view the markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually quite simple to do.

1. Pop the devtools out into its own window.
2. Hit the keyboard shortcut for opening the devtools, while your active window is the popped out devtools.
3. A second devtools window should come up to edit the first. Happy editing. =)

[Inspector Inception](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/contributing#step-3-inspector-inception)